# FortiClient 7.0.0.0018 + Ubuntu 22.04: Randomly having connection issues

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and FortiClient 7.0.0.0018  and I'm randomly having issues connecting to my VPN. One day I connect normally and then the next I'm not able to connect (I try restarting many times) and I get the following message: Config table failed. I've already found [this](https://community.fortinet.com/t5/Fortinet-Forum/FortiClient-VPN-not-connecting-on-Ubuntu-Backup-routing-table/td-p/210757) post, and many other similar and so far none have solved my issue.

Looking at the log these are the lines I find to be the most relevant:

```
20220926 11:56:45.265 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.266 [confighandler:DEBG] fct_websocket:251 Received message: FCT_UPDATE_TASK_START
20220926 11:56:45.270 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [2].
20220926 11:56:45.275 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.276 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [2].
20220926 11:56:45.282 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.282 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [2].
20220926 11:56:45.288 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.288 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [2].
20220926 11:56:45.294 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.294 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [2].
20220926 11:56:45.299 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.300 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [2].
20220926 11:56:45.304 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.305 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [20].
20220926 11:56:45.305 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:735 Table [fctdata]: Updating "av_engine_version"
20220926 11:56:45.305 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:735 Table [fctdata]: Updating "vul_sig_version"
20220926 11:56:45.305 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:735 Table [fctdata]: Updating "vul_engine_version"
20220926 11:56:45.305 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:735 Table [fctdata]: Updating "forticlient_sn"
20220926 11:56:45.321 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:678 Set fctdata DB success.
20220926 11:56:45.321 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 12 bytes.
20220926 11:56:45.323 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [2].
20220926 11:56:45.329 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 340 bytes.
20220926 11:56:46.349 [confighandler:DEBG] fct_websocket:203 Websocket client accepted
20220926 11:56:46.349 [confighandler:DEBG] fct_websocket:251 Received message: FCT_UPDATE_TASK_DONE
20220926 11:56:46.349 [confighandler:DEBG] fct_websocket:390 Client dropped from the set of webserver connections
20220926 11:56:46.350 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:305 Received request [9].
20220926 11:56:46.350 [confighandler:DEBG] fctconfig_handler:273 Sent 45 bytes.
```

Has anyone ever had a similar issue? How did you manage to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Try to go in your wi-fi settings, open the connection you are using and then un-check the box *"make available to other users"*